# \n are not added in text file

Tags: c#, file, io, text-files

i am trying to write into a text file in C#. My input is following

```
string input = "46 47\n 48 49";
```

I expected this to be write like the following

**46 47**

**48 49**

But it writes like

**46 47**
**48 49**

I am using the following code

```
string input = "46 47\n 48 49";
string path = @"d:\temp\MyTest.txt";

File.WriteAllText(path, input);
```

Comment: A newline on (presumably) Windows is \r\n. Use the [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) construct for a better experience all around.

Comment: Escape `\r\n` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine` like:

```
string input = "46 47\r\n48 49";
```

Or

```
string input = "46 47" + Environment.NewLine + "48 49";
```

EDIT: 
As far as modifying existing string value is concerned, you can do `String.Replace` like:

```
string newValue = input.Replace("\n",Environment.NewLine);
```

and then use `newValue` in `File.WriteAllText`

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) property to insert the new line:

```
string input = "46 47" + Environment.NewLine + "48 49";
```

As stated in the comments, new line in Windows environment can be achieved with `\r\n`, but it's better to use the `Environment.NewLine` option, as the MSDN states:

> The property value of NewLine is a constant customized specifically for the current platform and implementation of the .NET Framework

Comment: Problem is the string is a dynamic string so i cant add Environment.NewLine

Comment: If it is dynamic, how do you intent to add the \r\n anyway?

Comment: first i am reading from a text file which has new lines..as a result "\n" are assigned into the string variables

Comment: May be the way you read the file is incorrect? Why not try to read it line by line?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at the text file with Nodepad by any chance? Notepad cannot handle newlines as U+000A alone. It *needs* the CRLF sequence.

Your program is writing exactly what you want, but your editor won't show it correctly.

The better option here is, as J. Steen noted, to use `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way

```
string input = "46 47\n\n48 49";

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\Software\MyTest.txt", true))
            {
                foreach (char s in input)
                {
                    if (s == '\n')
                    {
                        sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else
                    sw.Write(s);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You could have done: `string newValue = input.Replace("\n",Environment.NewLine );`